# Drawing a shaded area under a probability distribution

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, distributions, filling

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31], x], {x, -8, 130}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Normal Distribution with mean=70.5,std.dev=14.31"]
Probability[70.5 - 14.31 < x < 70.5 + 2 14.31, 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31]]
```

How can I make the image fill the color corresponding to the range of probability?

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 dist = NormalDistribution[m, s];
 pdf = PDF[dist, x];
 Show[
  Plot[pdf, {x, m - 4 s, m + 4 s},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Automatic,
      Append[Flatten[
        Table[{
          {m + n*s, StringForm["μ+``σ", If[n == 1, "", n]]},
          {m - n*s, 
           StringForm["μ-``σ", If[n == 1, "", n]]}},
         {n, 1, 4}], 1], {m, "μ"}]}},
   Epilog -> {Text[StringForm["`` Pr\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``",
       Lighter[ColorData[97][1], .75],
       Probability[
        m + interval[[1]]*s < x < m + interval[[2]]*s, 
        x \[Distributed] dist]],
      Scaled[{.8, .8}]]}],
  Plot[pdf, {x, m + interval[[1]]*s, m + interval[[2]]*s},
   Filling -> Axis,
   PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}],
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {m, 0},
  PlotLabel -> 
   StringForm["Normal Distribution with mean=``, std.dev=``\n",
    m, s]],
 {{m, 70.5, "μ"}, -100, 100, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s, 14.31, "σ"}, 1, 20, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{interval, {-1, 2}}, -4, 4, 0.1,
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
  Method -> "Push",
  MinIntervalSize -> 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This image is really shocking! fantastic! But we can only calculate the probability of a closed interval. Can we modify it to calculate the probability of the left and right open intervals? For example, p (x>and x<). My idea is to make the code more universal

Comment: That is just `1 - Pr`. That is a minor addition (another `Text`) that you should be able to add. If you encounter a problem that you cannot resolve, then post a new question showing what you have tried and explaining your difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Show[{
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31], x], {x, #1, #2}, 
PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
,
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31], x], {x, -8, 130}, 
PlotRange -> All,PlotLabel -> "Normal Distribution with mean=70.5,std.dev=14.31"]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
] &[70.5 - 14.31, 70.5 + 2 14.31]
```

[image]

Comment: The image can be automatically filled according to the probability corresponding to the calculated interval, such as p (x>and x<), and the image in the range of (x>and x<) can be automatically filled with color. My idea is to make the code more universal

Comment: @csn899 You asked for "How can I make the image fill the color corresponding to the range of probability?" My answer gives the plot, depending on the range, not meor!

Comment: ```PlotLabel -> "Normal Distribution with mean=70.5,std.dev=14.31"```Why is this label not displayed?

Comment: Try `Show[{Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31], x], {x, #1, #2}, 
     PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31], x], {x, -8, 130}, 
     PlotRange -> All]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Normal Distribution with mean=70.5,std.dev=14.31"] &[
 70.5 - 14.31, 70.5 + 2 14.31]
`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dist = NormalDistribution[70.5, 14.31];
pdf = PDF[dist, x];
xl = Mean@dist - StandardDeviation@dist;
xr = Mean@dist + 2 StandardDeviation@dist;

max = First@Maximize[pdf, x];
prleft = (x /. Last@Maximize[pdf, x]) - 4.5 StandardDeviation@dist;
prright = (x /. Last@Maximize[pdf, x]) + 4.5 StandardDeviation@dist;

Show[
 Plot[pdf, {x, prleft, prright}
  , RegionFunction -> (xl < # < xr &)
  , Filling -> Axis
  , FillingStyle ->
   Nest[Lighter, ColorData[97, 1], 4]
  , PlotStyle -> None
  , PlotRange -> {
    {prleft, prright}
    , {0, max}
    }
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
  , ImagePadding -> {{20, 10}, {20, 20}}
  , Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}
  , AspectRatio -> 7/10
  , Epilog -> {
    Dashed, Red
    , Line[{{xl, 0}, {xl, pdf /. x -> xl}}]
    , Line[{{xr, 0}, {xr, pdf /. x -> xr}}]
    }
  
  ]
 ,
 Plot[pdf, {x, prleft, prright}
  , PlotStyle -> Thick
  , AxesOrigin -> {prleft - 1, 0}
  
  ]
 , PlotLabel -> 
  StringForm["\nNormal Distribution with mean = ``, std.dev = ``", 
   Style[Mean@dist, Red], Style[StandardDeviation@dist, Blue]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: The image can be automatically filled according to the probability corresponding to the calculated interval, such as p (x>and x<), and the image in the range of (x>and x<) can be automatically filled with color. My idea is to make the code more universal

Comment: `The image can be automatically filled...` : How?

Comment: If the probability of a certain interval is required, only the endpoint value and inequality symbol can be input to determine the interval. Then the image of the corresponding interval will be automatically filled with shadows