How to fill the function graph with colors according to this requirement?
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := 2^Floor[x]  Mod[x, 1]  (Mod[x, 1] - 1)
Plot[{f[x], -8/9}, {x, -2, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline"]

to get the function image:

How to fill the interior colors of all graphs on the left side of the first intersection point between the function graph and the line y==-8/9? The specific effects are as follows:


I've posted an answer, but you really should look through the documentation and this site to fill in the gaps of your knowledge. You've asked a number of questions for which answers can readily be found. I'm a relative novice in the art of asking and answering MMA SE questions, which is part of why i haven't posted duplicates, but part of the reason i'm unpracticed is that vary rarely fail to find an answer. numerous times i've drafted a question/answer only to discard it because in the process of streamlining for a MWE and researching the best way to precisely articulate, i find an answer.

Isn't this essentially the same as this previous question of yours?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282155/1871 I don't see your effort to understand answers you've obtained. (-1)

f[x_] := 2^Floor[x] Mod[x, 1] (Mod[x, 1] - 1);

end = NArgMin[(f[x] + 8/9)^2, x];

Plot[{f[x], If[x < end, f[x], None], -8/9}, {x, -2, 3},
 Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, Yellow}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]



A helpful note to a newbie:  Eliminate all unnecessary code.  For this problem, do you really care that the ImageSize is 500?  No.  Do you recall care that about the arrowheads?  No.  Do you really care about the label?  No.  AspectRatio?  No.
Eliminating useless portions will speed everything, and help you identify problems and solutions yourself.

Ok first, you don't want to use f[x] within the call to Plot in the way you've done. The SetDelayed[] meaning the := means the definition is called every point of the plot. or something. this is the main reason for slow plotting.  you would benefit from carefully perusing common pitfalls for new users
these both dramatically speed up the plot:
f[x_] := 2^Floor[x]   Mod[x, 1]   (Mod[x, 1] - 1)
(*using replace all*)
Plot[{f[xx] /. xx -> x, -8/9}, {x, -2, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline", Filling -> Top]

(*using evaluate*)
Plot[{Evaluate[f[x]], -8/9}, {x, -2, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLabels -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.04}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotHighlighting -> "Dropline", Filling -> Top]

Second, as indicated in that solution to the slow plotting, the option you are looking for is Filling here
To get the limit at x=constant, you could combine filling with piecewise plotting and Show[]
